# My Share Locale - get language

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-share

I'm using Alfresco Share and I have installed "My share locale" module that allows me to have the language selection on the login page. It works fine, labels are displayed in the selected language.
A problem has appeared when I wanted to use the selected language from my Java backed web script. I wanted to display some messages for users in a language they have selected in a dropdown menu, but when I use `I18NUtil.getLocale()`
the result is locale of my browser.
Does anyone know how to get the selected value in Java class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have never installed that plugin, but i suppose you adapt pretty much the same in your webscript what the plugin is doing for you:

https://github.com/linzhixing/AlfrescoMyShareLocale/blob/master/src/org/alfresco/module/mysharelocale/CustomLocaleResolver.java

get the cookie named "alf_share_locale"

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to get that cookie, but I run into a problem. I made HttpServletRequest with code: `public void execute(WebScriptRequest req, WebScriptResponse res) throws IOException { HttpServletRequest httpReq = WebScriptServletRuntime.getHttpServletRequest(req); Cookie[] cookies = httpReq.getCookies();` but the getCookies() method returns null.

Comment: when you're on the dashlet page, can you see the cookie when opening (chrome) dev console -> resources -> Cookies?

Comment: Yes, I see that cookie when I'm on the dashlet page, also when I'm on login page and the other pages.

Comment: please try readCookies from https://svn.rivetlogic.com/repos/rivets/core/cma/cma-alfresco/tags/cma-alfresco-1.1.1/src/main/java/com/rivetlogic/core/cma/alfresco/webscripts/bean/CmaWebScript.java

Comment: I saw that solution, but it doesn't work for me. For this line of code: `HttpServletRequest httpReq = ((WebScriptServletRequest) req).getHttpServletRequest();` I get the following error: _java.lang.ClassCastException: org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer$BufferedRequest cannot be cast to org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.WebScriptServletRequest..._ I did an internet search on that and tried to find the solution for this, or some other way to get HttpServletRequest from Web Script Request, but without success.

Comment: hum. did you try to get the cookie via a javascript controller?

Comment: well. the webscript controllers run on server side - you might need to  extend the plugin to save the value for alf_share_locale in a cookie and in a session as well i am afraid. hope i am right and i hope i could be of any help. sorry

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. You gave me a good idea, so I decided to use javascript to get cookie (`document.cookie`) and send that to my Java class as JSON.